# how do you convert date time '00:00 pm' into '00:00:00' in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to convert this timedate format into 00:00:00 how would I go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question a while back as well, and i found that this should work perfectly in typescript:

```
    convertTime12to24(time12h) {
    const [time, modifier] = time12h.split(' ');

    let [hours, minutes] = time.split(':');
    if (hours === '12') {
      hours = '00';
    }
    if (modifier === 'PM') {
      hours = parseInt(hours, 10) + 12;
    }
    return `${hours}:${minutes}:00`;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Awesome! Happy to help, sorry about that bracket at the end there.